# Get facebook user birthday and phone number

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

```
 let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){

                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if (fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil){

                    if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                    {
                        self.getFBUserData()
                    }
                }

            }

func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, gender, user_birthday, phone"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    //everything works print the user data
                    print(result)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get facebook user profile details. 
i am not getting birthday date and phone when i try to access it
How to change my code to get user's birthday date.
any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: please check privacy settings of account date of birth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook provide 3 permission `email`, `user_friends` and `public_profile` for that you dont need to put your app in facebook review. remain all you need to put your app for the review at developer.facebook.com

Here are all about permission:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Facebook clearly said:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make this change in ur code

```
func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, gender, birthday, phone"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    //everything works print the user data
                    print(result)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

And in Permissions array add
**@"user_birthday"**

Comment: adding "phone" to the array make the result (null) !

Comment: No "phone" available.

Comment: @NikKov Just don't down-vote. It depends on many privacy conditions for phone number in sdk. Check facebook latest tutorial for this

Comment: I didn't find any capabilities to fetch phone number from Facebook. Could you please provide a link for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){

                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if (fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil){

                    if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                    {
                        self.getFBUserData()
                    }
                }
```

@23/10/2002